# How to free memory in python?

Tags: memory-management

I am trying to traverse a list of .blend files to get the information inside them. However, I can not free the memory, causing the OOM error. The code is shown as below.

```py
dir_path = "path"
materials = os.listdir(dir_path)
dict_mapping = {}
for mat_name in materials:
    path_material = os.path.join(dir_path , mat_name)
    material      = load_blend(path_material, data_blocks="materials")  # load a blend file, and extract the material inside it.
    name          = None
    for mat in material:
        if name is None:
            name = mat.name
        else:
            name += "_"
            name += mat.name
        delete_material(mat)
    del material
    gc.collect()
    clear_all_objs()
    dict_mapping[mat_name.split(".")[0]] = name
def clear_all_objs():
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action="SELECT")
    bpy.ops.object.delete(use_global=False)
def delete_material(material):
    material.user_clear()
    bpy.data.materials.remove(material)
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried this, as shown in the code above: 
gc.collect()

Comment: I believe your problem is that `bpy.data.materials.remove` (and other remove functions) and `bpy.ops.object.delete` (and other delete functions) don't delete/remove but rather move the data to a clean up list that is only cleared when blender writes the modified blend file.